# SELECT no postgresql não pega registros no intervalo de tempo

Tags: postgresql

Tenho o seguinte SELECT

```
SELECT * FROM motoqueiros WHERE now() - INTERVAL '8 SECONDS' <= data_update
```

ele funciona na minha maquina local. Eu criei um server na AMAZON, o servidor tem o ubuntu 14 64 bits, quando executo o mesmo select não traz os resultados, eu tenho que colocar 20.000 segundos para que me retorne algo. Eu já alterei o fuso horário para América / São Paulo e nada, alguém já passou por esse tipo de coisa? obrigado!

Comment: Verificou se a versão do PostgreSQL é a mesma?

Comment: Lá é 9.3 a do pc é  9.4

Comment: Se possível, execute o SQL: `SELECT data_update, now() FROM motoqueiros ORDER BY data_update DESC LIMIT 15` e coloque na sua pergunta pra gente dar uma olhada.

Comment: deu esse resultado brother "2016-08-10 10:32:53"  - "2016-08-10 13:32:54.549232+00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o seu problema ainda seja a questão do fuso horário, já que o seu retorno de `now()` termina com `+00`, sendo que o nosso fuso (America/Sao_Paulo) é `-03`.

Tente o seguinte:

```
SELECT * FROM motoqueiros WHERE now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Sao_Paulo' - INTERVAL '8 SECONDS' <= data_update
```

Para resolver o problema de uma vez, edite o seu `postgresql.conf` com a seguinte entrada:

```
timezone = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
```

Comment: Essa solução deu certo brother, verifiquei aqui que quando dou reboot no ubuntu ele volta o timezone anterior, não tem outra forma não de fazer isso no SO não?

Comment: É só salvar a entrada `timezone` no `postgresql.conf` (está na resposta).

Comment: vdd, não tinha percebido, vlw!

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta. Abs